# How to change the order of the data from the model with arrays key in cakephp2?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I want to get the data from the model "$result = $this->MyData->geMyDataList($myIds);" in the following order from key[4 to 0] in decsending order. but the problem is I have no clue how to do it. How should I get the data in the decending order of the arrays key? I'm new to cakephp so sample will be great ! I would love to hear from you!

```
2017-12-21 18:40:22 Debug: select * my_data where id in ( 9184,10975,1070,9185,11497 )  limit 0, 20
2017-12-21 18:40:22 Debug: Array
(
    [4] => 9184 
    [3] => 10975
    [2] => 1070
    [1] => 9185
    [0] => 11497
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the database result is stored in `$results`, you can use either of the following:

```
ksort($results); // it gives array in ASC order
krsort($results); // it gives array in DESC order
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the array backwards, starting from 4 until 0, like this:

```
$result = []; //database result
for($i = count($result) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $result[$i]; //do something
}
```